# Kate / Kcalc - number pad using numbers and functions at the same time

Tags: kubuntu, numpad

OS: Kubuntu 23.04 x86_64

I have a problem that I just don't really know how to search for so maybe someone can point me in the right direction.  All I can seem to find is people having problems getting their numlock on at boot.

This seems to only happen when using Kate, Kcalc, or at least that's all that I've noticed so far.  If I try and use the number pad to enter numbers, say to enter the number 0, it will sometimes enter a 0 and sometimes toggle Insert mode.  The same for the other keys, 4 will give me a 4 or back the cursor one space, 7 or home etc.  It's almost like the numlock is on and off at the same time.  Any suggestion on what to do?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

After more testing this appears to be some sort of weird interaction with Barrier and Kate / Kcalc.  Using a keyboard connected directly to the machine I don't get the same behavior.

Thanks